# Крашанка: питоме чи запозичене слово?

Tags: значення-слів

Часто чую вживаннях таких обох термінів:

Пи́санка — яйце, декороване традиційними символами, які пишуться за допомогою воску й барвників. Цей вид мистецтва поширений у багатьох народів світу.

Кра́шанка (галунка) — один з чотирьох основних видів розписаних великодніх яєць, разом з крапанкою, дряпанкою, та писанкою.
Визначення понять взяла із [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/).

Хвилює те, чи “крашанка” - це, випадково, не русизм? Чи нормативно вживати це слово, чи слід уникати і використовувати "писанка"? Адже є у російській мові слова “красить, украшать”.

Comment: Це питомо українське слово. «Краса» та похідні від нього є в _усіх_ слов'янських мовах. А ще в українській є «прикрашати».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Згідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/krashanka) та до [Публічного електронного словника Української мови](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) слово "Крашанка" може вживатися в українській мові у значенні "Пофарбоване куряче яйце, призначене для великодніх свят", а також як діалектизм може означати слово "яйце".